# Continue with Object serialization or use database?

Tags: java, relational-database, derby, object-serialization

I have written a math game in Java, and have distributed some copies to a few beta-testers. The problem is that the version I have given them is saving the GameData via object serialization, which I found out is mainly for sending Objects, or in this case, ArrayLists of GameData, over a network. It is NOT persistance; that is what a relational database is for. Knowing this, I would like to know if it would be better to create a database on the beta-tester's machine (and rewrite the game), or continue with the Object serialization version of the game, and then retrieve the Objects when they are ready to send the data?

My guess would be to just move their data to a database that is created on their computer, and then give them the database version of the game. That way, the data can be persisted and be much easier to manipulate. What turns me away from that idea is the question of how am I going to write their database into mine (in the future)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although relatively rare, there are still lots of applications that use serialization for storage and retrieval of objects. It's not *wrong* to do this, just slightly unusual. **If it's working for you, stick with it** because DB's are a heavyweight solution. What you found out, about serialization, is only an opinion and an ill-formed one at that.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of using an embedded database, two options to consider are [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) and [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/). However, serialization is also an option, and in my opinion it should be your default option if you've already implemented it.  Some considerations:

1. With serialization you've generally got to retrieve the entire object, which is slow if you've got an object with several dozen fields and you only want to read one of them. If you're making queries like these, then use a database. I suspect that you're just reading in all of your serialized objects at startup and serializing them back out to disk at shutdown, in which case there's no reason to use a database instead of serialization.
2. Java's default serialization mechanism is fairly slow. You may want to consider another serialization mechanism, such as [Kryo](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), but only if you're not happy with your program's serialization performance.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to advise on the best choice of technology without knowing what you are persisting and why.

- If the state is simply a snapshot of your game state (i.e. a save file) or a "best scores" table, then you don't need a database.  Serializing using JSON, XML or ... Java Object serialization is sufficient.
- If the state needs to be read or updated incrementally or shared with other applications ... or users on other machines ... then a database is more appropriate.

  Serialization mechanisms are problematic if the requirements include incremental changes, etcetera.  You end up building a database-like layer over the top of the serialization.

---

As to whether you should stick with Java serialization ... or switch to JSON or XML or something like that:

- Object serialization is simple, but it can be fragile if you change the classes that you are serializing.  This fragility can be mitigated, but it is messy and you lose the simplicity.  (You need to write custom `readObject` and `writeObject` methods that know how to read "old versions" of the serialized objects.)
- JSON and XML are a bit more complicated, but still relatively simple if you use an object binding mechanism.

It is worth noting that changes to the persisted object classes (or the database schemas) are potentially problematic no matter what you do.  There is no easy universal solution to this problem.

---

**UPDATE**

Given the additional information that you provided in your first comment (below), it seems like you don't need a database in the game itself. All you need is something that can read and analyse the session state save files that your beta testers provide for you. Indeed, it doesn't even seem like the actual app needs to be able read the files. (But that's unclear, because you've not said what the real purpose of these files is ... or at least, not what the entire purpose is.)

It is also worth noting that you are probably saving the wrong information if your aim is to tune the sets of questions. What you really need to do is record the length of time and whether the user got the right or wrong answer and the time ... for each individual question. And you probably need to know what the actual answer given was ... so that you can spot cases where the user's answer was actually right and you "marked" it as wrong ... or vice versa.

> "What turns me away from that idea is the question of how am I going to write their database into mine (in the future)?"

Exactly.  If you hadn't prematurely "analysed" the data, you wouldn't have this problem.

But ignoring that, it seems like that a simple state saving mechanism is sufficient to meet your (still *hypothetical* / *inferred*) requirement of keeping a personal score board for the end user.  Your "tuning" stuff would be better implemented using a custom log file.  I cannot see any value in incorporating a database as part of the app itself.

Comment: As stated in my question, I am serializing an `ArrayList` of `GameData` each time the game is saved (once per session). The `GameData` consists of `difficultyLevel`, number of problems right, number of problems wrong, `completionTime`, and `gameMode`. The information I expect from the beta-testers (what I will need to make further improvements to the game) will be two tables analyzing all the data and having information such as `difficultyLevel`, fastest, slowest, and average time, number of problems right and wrong (altogether) and overall accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are doing java serialisation, If so there is nothing wrong with it. Just be aware of its limitations - Different versions of java might not be able to retrieve the file.
Also If you change the Class, previous saved data can not be retrieved.

If you decide to change you could look at Xml, JSon, Protocol Buffers, Thrift, Avro etc as well as a DB.

Note:

```
  Xml is builtin in to java 
  Java Db (Derby) is also in Java
```

Other serialisation schema's require a seperate library.

Comment: Yes, I am doing Java serialization, and I have already backed up MY data to a Derby database //I am a beta-tester, too..

Comment: You could continue with java serialisation in the Interim but be ready change if necesary / when you need to change the saved data.